# Generate HTTP RESTful server from database schema

Tags: database, rest, sql, schema

Today the job of most Java-based servers is to translate HTTP requests into SQL commands/queries and send a JSON-ed response back to the client. That's a pretty generic (and honestly boring) job.

I wonder is there a mature solution that can generate a working RESTful server out of my relational database schema? Possibly adding some features like request authorization, so a guest wouldn't be able to drop any table, and an IFTTT service, so I can, for instance, send a notification e-mail when a new user is registered.

Comment: probably ought to ask on softwarerecs.se

Comment: "Today the job of most Java-based servers is to translate HTTP requests into SQL commands/queries and send a JSON-ed response back to the client. That's a pretty generic (and honestly boring) job." - yeah that's not even close to remotely true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Today the job of most Java-based servers is to translate HTTP requests into SQL commands/queries and send a JSON-ed response back to the client.

Do you have a source to back this up?

In my experience, at least, most service APIs have some domain logic between the Database and the API itself.  **And that's where their value lies.**

In those cases, you should really think twice about coupling your database representation of your domain concepts to the API representations.  Doing so means every time you decide to change your db schema you automatically change your service API as well.

Comment: May you give an example of how such domain logic looks like exactly?

Comment: @EvgeniyGryaznov https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/234254/308851

Comment: Thanks @DanWilson, that's a perfect response.